# SQL Azure. Change tracking

Tags: azure-sql-database, change-tracking

After some time googling I've found that Change Data Capture functionality is not supported on SQL Azure. This is frustrating for me because I'd like to implement change tracking without significant code changes, which are needed in case of implementing it.

Is there any built-in functionality for changes tracking in SQL Azure?

---

*In case it really cannot be used in SQL Azure - what libraries or products can provide this functionality for enterprise scale project?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v12, SQL Azure supports Change Tracking(NOT Change Data Capture). Which is better than using Triggers and adding extra columns to track changes.

Comment: But is change tracking as useful as CDC? Change tracking does not save the versions of the data. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2976.how-to-enable-sql-azure-change-tracking.aspx), which describes the workaround of adding a "Local Data Cache" item to a VS project. Apparently this merely adds some datetime columns to your DB tables and populates them with triggers, which seems like a shoddy alternative in my opinion. (In particular: I'd be cautious about whether that datetime is set as the transaction commit time or as the insertion time, which could cause changes to be missed in concurrency scenarios depending on how you're handling updates.)